# Finding and editing a WordPress site in cpanel w/o access to WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cpanel

I have a client who needs his website edited, he is no longer in contact with the original creator of the site, and it seems that the creator used WordPress to make the website. I've been able to access the page through cPanel but cannot locate the HTML files necessary to do things such as editing text. I have the ability to change images but the owner would like to remove some pages, etc.

There are also tons of PHP files for the WordPress extensions and such, but I know nothing about PHP.

Would I need access to the wp-admin account that designed the page in order to modify the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress stores page content in a database, which is subsequently loaded by a collection of php files. You cannot change the content or looks of a wordpress site by changing html files.

The easiest way to change content is to log in to the wordpress dashboard of the website. If you don't have the password, you can open up phpmyadmin via cpanel, browse to the wordpress database and find the `*yourwebsiteinitials*_users` table. In there you can choose one of the accounts that should be there and click edit, then edit the user_pass column, and simply type a new password in `value` and set `function` to md5. Then you can go to `*yourwebaddress*/wp-login.php` in your browser and login with the user you just edited and the new password.

Alternatively you can find posts in the _posts table and change content via phpmyadmin, but it's much easier to do this via the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

You can log into the WordPress dashboard from the cPanel, following these steps:

1. Login to cPanel.
2. Scroll down to the Softaculous Apps Installer section and click on the WordPress icon:

[image: Softaculous Apps Installer]

3. You will be directed to the WordPress Install tab.
4. Scroll down to the Current Installations section.
5. Click on the admin icon to login to the WordPress dashboard without a password:

[image: click admin icon]

6. You will then reach the WordPress admin dashboard- voila!

[image: WordPress admin dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few things you need to be aware of: and I believe you have a good understanding of WordPress. If not you may want to watch some tutorials about it.

1. Themes: You need to find out if the previous developer develop with custom template and maybe he hard coded all the text inside themes file which located wp-content/themes/{name of the theme}/ {other file}, in this case, if you are not aware of WordPress theme development or how it structure, I suggest you watch some quick tutorial on it and there are tons.
2. Yes, wp-admin is the place where you can find all the pages listed or posts or whatever content. By editing page, you easily can change the text or delete the page which not require or add a new page.

Just find what is the way it's coded. then you will able to follow

Comment: I've gone through every file, every `.html` file contains nothing, the rest are `php` files or images. Manipulating the websites' elements doesn't seem possible through the themes files

Comment: The please just login to wp-admin and you can do it from there.

Answer (score 0):

if you want delete page in WORDPRESS you need to login wordpress and delete from pages and if you need delete custom php pages you need to go to cpanel and public html folder your page name or delete from wordpress go to /public_html/wp-content/themes/active theme name/ and find there page name there extenstion of pages is like pagename.php or pagename.html.